# Pretty print in VIM?

Tags: vim, printf

I have few lines that each of them are colon separated values,

`abc:def:3`

Now I could do the reformat with printf plus IFS variable,

`while read line; do IFS=":" printf "%-20s  %-16s  %5d\n" ${line[0]} ${line[1]} ${line[2]}; done < XX`

but is it possible to do it within VIM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, in the `vi` spirit, you'd call a command to do it like:

```
:%!column -ts:
```

(if you have `column` and it supports the `-s` option).

Otherwise you could do:

```
:%s/[^:]\+/                                        &/g
:%s/\v^ *([^:]{20}): *([^:]{16}): *([^:]{5})/\1:\2:\3/
```